# Unity 3D audio playback

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added some oudiofiles from finder to unity project navigator. Some of tham plays fine, but others... unity dont show any information about tham in plreview window (it's size and all other parameters are zero), sound doesn't plays. But I can double-click on tham, and thay will play in iTunes as usual.
I found, that all files I can't play in Unity has duration less than 1 second. Is this is sourse of my problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making audiofiles longer then 1 second solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sound files less than 1 sec shouldn't be a problem in general as I have a couple of them working fine.

Check that the [audio format is supported](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/AudioFiles.html), Unity3D supports only a few of them and Apple's .aac for example is not one of them. If that doesn't work, I would convert these small files into an uncompressed format like .wav and try it this way. They recommend uncompressed formats for perfomance reasons but may be there is problem rising occasionally.

Comment: Thanks for information, but making audiofiles longer then 1 second solved my problem.